# Why does not Value type arguments in Generics share native code?

Tags: c#, generics

To avoid the code explosion in Generics CLR considers the all reference type arguments to be identical so that code can be shared (CLR can perform this optimization because all reference arguments or variables are really just pointers).However, this does not happen if any type argument is a value type
and the reason given is that "Value type can vary in size".

So my question is  what is special about Value type which makes it vary its size and how does that relates to native code not being shared for value type argument?

Comment: What is that about "...how does that relates to native code..."? Why should any of this relate to native code? I don't understand.

Comment: @elgonzo "the value type can vary in size", and hence there is no sharing of native code for them. I'm asking why varying size of value types restricts the CLR from sharing the native code for them.

Comment: What native code? Native code is not CLR. Native code is produced by C++ or Delphi/Lazarus compilers, for example, or by writing a program in x86 assembler. I think you do not mean native code when saying "native code". But what do you mean?

Comment: when I say native code, I mean JIT compiled code. The CLR takes the method's IL and substitute the specified type argument, and then creates native code that is specific to that method operating on that specific data types.

Comment: Ah, yes. Now i get you... the size of the generic arguments have an impact of the memory layout that is realized by the JIT'ed code of the generic, thus in the best case code could only be shared for generics whose generic parameters would be of the same size...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have two classes

```
class C1
{
    public int I1;
}

class C2
{
    public int I1;
    public int I2;
    public int I3;
}
```

A variable of type C1 has the same size as a variable of type C2. Since classes are **reference types** the size of those variables is the size of a reference, which is always the same and constant.

Now let's look at a similar scenario, but using structs:

```
struct S1
{
    public int I1;
}

struct S2
{
    public int I1;
    public int I2;
    public int I3;
}
```

Note that structs are **value types**, they are not **reference types**.

A variable of type S1 has a different size than a variable of type S2.

The size of a variable of type S1 = sizeof(I1)
The size of a variable of type S2 = sizeof(I1) + sizeof(I2) + sizeof(I3)

(In reality, depending on the type of the members of a struct, the struct size could be even slightly larger if the the compiler decides to add padding bytes to the struct for reasons related to memory access performance. But since it does not matter for the explanation here, i suggest you ignore padding in the context of this question.)

Ofcourse this is not only limited to variables, but obviously also true for field and property types as well as method parameters.

Imagine, you create your own Generic class:

```
class MyGeneric<T>
{
    public void DoSomething(T parameter)
    {...}
}
```

Using the structs i defined above (S1 and S2), then it is obvious that the argument "parameter" of the *DoSomething* method for the `MyGeneric<S1>` class has a different size than the same argument of the the `MyGeneric<S2>` class.

Comment: Okay. Hope that also answered the question you had regarding "native code". :)